# React render insert adjacent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, insertadjacenthtml

How do I specify position relative to the element when calling React render on an element and its container?

i.e.
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('divInTheBody'));

Say I want to insert this element before the element itself ('beforebegin').
How do I do that?

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: You can't. Dynamically insert a new element there and render your react component into it.

Answer (score 0):

First, add an 'id' to the JSX element you want to manipulate -

```
<div id="foo" style={{position: 'relative'}}> Some Text</div>
```

Now in your component, you can call

```
useEffect(() => {
    let elem = document.getElementById('foo')
    elem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', 
        <div style={{position: 'absolute' bottom:'10px'}}>
            Dynamic Component
        </div>)
}, [])
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.